How to load a returned GeoJSON into a WebMap of a Web Application
My goal is to have a web application with a Leaflet webmap that will display a GeoJSON file as layer, based on id from user input.
Current setup: Node, ejs, express, Leaflet
A folder with multiple GeoJSON files saved on the server named by id.
project/data/1053.geojson
project/data/1065.geojson
project/data/1436.geojson
etc.
ejs page with a user input text field and button and a Leaflet map.
        <div class="container">
        <a href="/dtbverschilkaart/create">Nieuwe Verschilkaart Maken</a>
        
        <form id="geojsonForm">
            <label for="geojsonId">Bestaande verschilkaart bekijken op basis van ID:</label>
            <input type="text" id="geojsonId" name="geojsonId" required>
            <button type="submit" class="buttonstyle">Inladen</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="container"></div>   
    <script src="/verschilkaart.js"></script>   

A router that finds and returns the right .geojson in the folder, based on the ID in the GET request url.
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
const id = req.query.geojsonId; // Get the ID from the URL
const geojsonPath = path.join(__dirname, '../data', `${id}.geojson`);

// Check if the file exists
fs.readFile(geojsonPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("File Read Error:", err.message);
        return res.render('dtbverschilkaart');
    }
    try {
        const geojsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        res.json(geojsonData);
    } catch (parseError) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Error parsing GeoJSON file" });
    }
});
});

A public JavaScript file verschilkaart.js for the base layer and soon GeoJSON layer
const map = L.map('map').setView([52.1, 5.50], 7);
var osmUrl='https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png';
var osmAttrib='Map tiles by CartoDB, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL';
var osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
minZoom: 1, 
maxZoom: 20, 
attribution: osmAttrib
}).addTo(map);

I currently do not get errors, the router returns the correct .geojson to my browser.
How to I make it so it returns the GeoJSON to the Leaflet map and loads it as a layer?

I resolved by sending the GeoJSON as string to frond-end changing the routing:
const geojsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        res.render('webpage', { geojson: geojsonData } );

And then on the front-end using ejs calling a function that adds it as layer
const inputGeojson = <%- JSON.stringify(geojson) %>;
loadGeojson(inputGeojson);
function loadGeojson(input) {
L.geoJSON(input).addTo(map);
};

